# How to do balance partitions of tasks in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, load-balancing, partition

it ran my `keyBy`, `map` and `flatMap` transformations for large data.

Let's look at it too:

[image]

and Here is my code example:

```
val data1 = sc.parallelize(Seq(("aa", 1), ("ba", 2), ("bc", 2), ("b", 3), ("c", 1)))
val data2 = sc.parallelize(Seq(("a", 3), ("b", 5)))

val result: RDD[(String, Int)] = data1
      .keyBy(_._1.substring(0, 1)) // key by first character
      .cogroup(data2)
      .filter { case (_, (_, data2Values)) => data2Values.nonEmpty }
      .flatMap { case (_, (data1Values, _)) => data1Values }
```

This is not well balanced across the tasks. Why?

So I tried to use `repartition`, but It was not worked.

**Questions**

1. Why is the partition going to one side of the task?
2. Is there a method to solve this problem.

Comment: Is it possible to post a code snippet to see what kind of processing you're doing and how you're repartitioning?

Comment: I added a code snippet. The data is a just example to see easily. Actually, I use large data. Whether or not using `repartition`  I just want the tasks to have a balanced partition...

Comment: Are you sure on your real data you're getting more than 1 key?  Check data1.keyBy(_._1.substring(0, 1)).keys.distinct.count and data2.keys.distinct.count

Comment: yes `data1.keyBy(_._1.substring(0, 1)).keys.distinct.count
=> res18: Long = 3` and `data2.keys.distinct.count
=> res21: Long = 2`

Comment: The code looks ok and with the sample datasets above I see data getting distributed across multiple tasks. With default parallelism of 8 in the spark UI l see for the cogroup stage 3 partitions with 4,2,1 rows (the rest 0 rows as you have 3 keys)

Comment: Apart from my example, Do you know why the partitions are skewed to one task?